# Possible to use Single URL for multiple tomcats

Tags: apache, tomcat

I have several tomcat deployments which can be accessed via 3 separate URLs.

e.g. http://app1.example.com, http://app2.example.com, http://app3.example.com

I want to have only one URL that will automatically forward requests to the appropriate tomcat depending on the user logged in.

e.g. http://app.example.com

If I log in as john, all of my requests are processed by app1.example.com.  If I log in as bob, all of my requests are processed b app3.example.com.

I don't want the separate URLs to be exposed if possible. The user should stay on the single URL in their browser's address bar.

How can I do this?

Comment: you mean like load balancer?

Comment: Possibly. I don't know enough about how load balancers work to know if they are the answer to my situation. Can load balancers be configured to selectively route certain requests based on certain criteria?