# Possible to use a custom load balancing policy for Tomcat 7?

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7, load-balancing

This is a variant of the previous question I asked:
[Possible to use Single URL for multiple tomcats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16567837/possible-to-use-single-url-for-multiple-tomcats)

I noticed that Tomcat's load balancer, JK, supports round-robin weighted load balancing.

I'm wondering if it is possible for me to implement a custom load balancing policy that I can somehow plug into JK, or some alternative load balancer that works with Tomcat?

The only references to custom load balancer policies I could find are from Tomcat 5.x, which allows you to extend org.apache.webapp.balancer.Rule to implement a custom load balancer rule... but I'm not sure if this is still possible with Tomcat 7.

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat6/7 can be configure with Apache+mod_cluster.

http://www.devx.com/Java/Article/48086/0/page/1
http://www.jboss.org/mod_cluster

In mod_cluster it is possible to calculate load on different factor.

http://docs.jboss.org/mod_cluster/1.1.0/html/java.AS7config.html

mod_cluster uses load balance factors calculated and provided by the application servers, rather than computing these in the proxy

Comment: +1 **but**, please, do not refer to the old documentation for mod_cluster 1.1.x and definitely use mod_cluster [1.2.0+](http://docs.jboss.org/mod_cluster/1.2.0/html_single/). The best version that one can get is 1.2.6, yet, there are no zips to download yet, so one has to compile it...   We will prepare the zips presently :-)

Comment: And here they are mod_cluster 1.2.6 binaries: http://www.jboss.org/mod_cluster/downloads/1-2-6-Final-bin